# Mule Proxy Service can't find definition in namespace

Tags: namespaces, mule

I've set up a few proxy services in mule, but still learning.  For some reason this flow doesn't work when the namespace and service name should be correct.  Anybody see my error?

Thanks for the time

```
<flow name="UPCFlow1" doc:name="UPCFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="4040" path="upc" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:proxy-service namespace="http://searchupc.com/" service="GetProduct" payload="envelope" wsdlLocation="http://www.searchupc.com/service/UPCSearch.asmx?WSDL"  doc:name="SOAP" port="UPCSearchSoap"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint address="http://www.searchupc.com/supc/service/UPCSearch.asmx"
    exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

This is from the stack trace

```
INFO  2012-10-12 11:06:44,739 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'upc' never started, nothing to dispose of
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for service {http://searchupc.com/}GetProduct.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in your configuration: the service name is "UPCSearch" not "GetProduct".

This works:

```
<flow name="UPCFlow1" doc:name="UPCFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="4040" path="upc" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <cxf:proxy-service namespace="http://searchupc.com/"
        service="UPCSearch" payload="envelope"
        wsdlLocation="http://www.searchupc.com/service/UPCSearch.asmx?WSDL"
        doc:name="SOAP" port="UPCSearchSoap" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint
        address="http://www.searchupc.com/supc/service/UPCSearch.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks David, you seem to be everywhere with these Mule Answers.
I'm getting an COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM error now, but the original issue solved

Comment: LOL, I'm everywhere near Mule http://manning.com/dossot2/ :) Open a new issue with this new problem please.

Comment: Yea, gonna try and trouble shoot it myself and will open new post if needed.